# Monthly ADFv2 Schedule trigger creation requirement

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have requirement to create ADFv2 schedule trigger as follow

1. Last 2 days + First 4 days of every month
2. Excluding weekend i.e. Saturday & Sunday
3. Four times in a day after every three hours i.e 9:00, 12: 00, 3:00 & 6:00 Hours

I am not getting any solution to exclude weekend in case, if it is coming in between last 2 days + first 4 days of every month. Hence really appreciated any help for the same.

Kindly let me know in case, you need more details on the same.

Thanks,

Amit Garg

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#examples-recurrence-schedules

```
{
    "name": "TR_DATA_Master_MonthStartNEnd_Raw_EDW",
    "properties": {
        "description": "TR_DATA_Master_MonthStartNEnd_Raw_EDW",
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "Delete the files",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Month",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2019-05-15T09:02:00.000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                       0
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        9,12,15,18
                    ],
                    "monthDays": [
                        -1,
                        -2,
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find out, how to exclude weekends i.e. Saturday & Sunday so that in case last 2 or first 4 days of month are coming on weekend then on that particular days, above schedule trigger should not get fired.

Comment: Please avoid sentences like *provide [...] solution at high priority.* - it's rude. Based on your [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger-definition) you can define `weekDays` in your [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-property)